# Why does state clear after refreshing page?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, antd

I'm having a problem with ant design components. I have a table with document names and forms. After refreshing page, state cleares, although I don't clear it myself. How can I avoid it?
If I use `defaultValue` attribute, it doesn't help me because after refreshing it's empty. Does somebody have any idea how to save state after refreshing?

Comment: You should use a global state management such as `Redux`

Comment: In order to preserve the state when reloading the page you'll have to use local or session storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The local state in your component or even the redux-store will be cleared when the browser refresh. Because the are in-memory data.

If you want to preserve the state, then you can copy or take a snapshot of the sate and put it in your localstorage. You will have to copy the state to your local storage during `window.onunload` event. and when the page loads again get the values from local storage and patch them in you state